# Google: "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

Users in my website keep getting this error everytime they choose to sign in using google.
I have had a look at related public questions to find a solution, but nothing seems to work, because my code is slightly different.

Here is what the REGISTER page does in this case:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . "/data_inc/google.php";
$loginURL = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
```

```html
<a onclick="window.location = '<?=$loginURL?>'" class="oauth-container btn darken-4 white black-text" style="text-transform:none">
        <div class="left">
            <img style="margin-top:7px; margin-right:8px" alt="Google sign-in" 
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" />
        </div>
        With Google
    </a>
```

Here is the code which does the main part, which is google.php

```php
session_start();
 require_once "/home/tonevrec/public_html/vendor/autoload.php";
 $gClient = new Google_Client();
 $gClient->setClientId("92382394890-324098239048239084id0234824.apps.googleusercontent.com");
 $gClient->setClientSecret("GNALER-l_wO1DJwbcjUNa02812l7KlS6p");
 $gClient->setApplicationName("Tonevre");
 $gClient->addScope(scope_or_scopes:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
 $gClient->setRedirectUri('https://tonevre.com');
```

Does anyone know what I should do; Download anything, write new code, or even remove something? If anybody needs more details, please send a message. Thank you for reading!

Comment: YOU need to add this URL - https://tonevre.com to your Google API console. Add the URL with different format, with and without https.

Comment: _Side note:_ I have to ask, why this `<a onclick="window.location = '<?=$loginURL?>'"` over just doing `<a href="<?=$loginURL?>"`?

Comment: Btw, if those are your actual cliend id and client **secret**, you've just leaked them to the entire internet, and you should then change those credentials ASAP. _Never_ share any type of credentials.

Comment: @M.Eriksson The ids which are provided in my questions, are in fact false and madeup. I am completely aware of the consequences of leaking such information.

Comment: Nice. It's not uncommon that people miss that when posting. Just a suggestion, if you use `****` instead, it makes it more clear :-)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Do you see anything more off then the a element? I have no idea on why this is not working..

Comment: If you've added the exact same redirect URL when you configured the app in Google as you've done in your code, it should work. Is it really the first page you want as the redirect URL? Not saying it's wrong, but it's more common that you have a specific URL, where you can set the user session etc for the site, and then you redirect them to where you want them to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

YOU need to add this URL - tonevre.com to your Google API console. Add the URL with different format, with and without https

Comment: I have just tried to implement a URL without the https, and it won't allow such URLs in the Google API console.

Comment: Maybe you were trying different way. Take a look at this screenshot - https://prnt.sc/wBnTrbGWfyKT